# Enable click-through without overriding NSView acceptsFirstMouse

Tags: macos, gtk, macos-carbon

The proper way of enabling click-though is to override acceptsFirstMouse on an NSView to return YES. (Click-through means that you can click on and use a control even when its window is not focused. For example, the Finder toolbar buttons, and the traffic-light window controls use this.)

My problem is that my application is not based on Cocoa, but GTK. Under the hood, GTK uses some Carbon and Cocoa, and I can get a pointer to the NSView if I want - but I can't get the widget to use a different NSView subclass without editing the GTK source. What are other ways to achive click-through?

(And, if possible, "hover-through" - I'd like to have mouse-over events on the click-through controls, too, so I can highlight them, telling the user that they are clickable.)

I could call Carbon's InstallWindowEventHandler with kEventWindowGetClickActivation, but I'm not sure how to use it, and if it's going to work (I've read Carbon is deprecated and might not work on modern Macs anymore). Alternatively, there must be a low-level mechanism to enable this (the Cocoa mechanism has to be implemented somehow). Any ideas?